# Python Paramiko SFTP Open File start from N-line

Tags: python, python-3.x, sftp, paramiko

Because my file in the server is huge and I and to save the time to downloading the file from the server so I using paramiko `sftp.open(file)` to read the file in the server.

Is there any ways that we can start reading the file from any line of the file using `sftp.open(file)` or others?

---

This how I used to read the file from local directory

```
# open the file and start reading from the nth line
for line in itertools.islice(file, no_line, None):
    print(line)
```

---

This how I read the file from the server

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect(host, port, username, password)
readfile = ssh.open_sftp()
file = readfile.open(os.path.join(path, file))
for line in file:
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no API in SFTP that would allow you to skip to N-th line.

You can start reading from N-th byte though, using [`SFTPFile.seek` method](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_file.SFTPFile.seek):

```
file = readfile.open(os.path.join(path, file))
file.seek(offset)
for line in file:
    print(line)
```